# ¿Es posible hacer un JQuery que actué sobre el objeto que solo se este clickeando?

Tags: jquery, css

Me explico hice un código el cual da la propiedad `toggle` a todos los que sean de cierta clase pero al momento de dar un `click`, abre todos los de esa clase no solo el que doy `click`.

Bueno espero que se haga en cada uno con la propiedad `toggle` no en todos cuando `clikeo` uno.

```
$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu").toggle(300);
});
```

**Como se ve:**

[image: Toggle]

**Como debiera verse:**

[image: Togglee]

**Con la propiedad this se esconde el menu:**

[image: Togglethis]

**Mi HTML**

```
                    $obtenermenu=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tblnoticias_menu where descripcion!='EVALUACIONES' order By PosI");
                    while($menu=mysqli_fetch_array($obtenermenu))
                    {
                        $submenu=mysqli_query($link,"Select * from tblnoticias_submenu where idopcion='$menu[idopcion]' and estado=1 Order By PosS");
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($submenu)>0) 
                        {
                            ?>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown mr-auto">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="margin-left:200px;">
                    <span><?php echo utf8_encode($menu['descripcion']); ?></span> <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu ">
                    <?php
                            while($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($submenu))
                            {
                                ?>

                        <li>
                            <a style="text-decoration: none;color:black" href="<?php echo " /../../".$row1['url'];?>">
                                <?php echo utf8_encode($row1['descripcion']); ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>

                        <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <?php
                        }
                    }

            ?>



                <?php
    mysqli_close($link);

?>
                    <div id="busqueda">
                    <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search" id="busqueda">
                        <div class="input-group add-on">
                            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar" type="text">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
        </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Publica el html de tu menu para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Ahí hice una edición de la pregunta con el html

Comment: Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utiliza `this` que da la referencia del elemento que lanzo el evento. Luego buscas al padre de ese elemento para buscar el sub-menu y le aplicas el toggle:

```
$(".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function(){
    $(this).parent() //  seria el <li class="nav-item dropdown mr-auto">
    .find("ul.dropdown-menu") // buscamos el sub-menu
     .toggle(300); // le aplicamos el toggle
});
```

Comment: Ya lo probe con this pero esconde el item al cual le doy un click

Comment: Y no es eso lo que quieres? Que actue solo sobre el elemento que se le hace clic? Explicate un poco mejor para poder entender.

Comment: que actué sobre el submenu no en el menú, ¿me explico?, agregue una imagen con tu solucion para que veas que ocurre.

Comment: Gracias acabas de solucionar mi problema, muy agradecido por tu tiempo y conocimiento brindado.

Answer (score 4):

Ajusta tu funcion del `click` para que se guie solo del objeto clickeado:

```
$( ".dropdown-toggle" ).click(function(){
    $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").toggle(300);
});
```

Comment: Con esta respuesta toma solo el que seleccionas pero pierde la propiedad toggle, saludos.

Comment: Acabo de probarlo y no hay problema, quizás tenga algún conflicto con otro código. Suerte

Comment: me refiero a que si se ve el submenu, pero no con la propiedad toggle.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí un ejemplo tomando tu estructura html.

```js
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){
 
  $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').toggleClass('show');

})
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

.dropdown-toggle {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu {
   display: none;
   position: absolute;
   top: 100%;
}

.dropdown-menu.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>

  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Uno</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>uno</li>
      <li>dos</li>
      <li>tres</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Uno</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>uno</li>
      <li>dos</li>
      <li>tres</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Uno</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>uno</li>
      <li>dos</li>
      <li>tres</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
    
</ul>
```

Utiliza el método .siblings(selector) para el objeto $(this):

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){

  $(this).siblings('.dropdown-menu').toggle(300);

});
```

Aquí te dejo la [documentación en jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Comment: pierde la movilidad de toggle con esta opcion.

Comment: utiliza el último ejemplo, ahí lo complete. debería funcionar.